# Address Book - Errors

Tags: java

I'm working on an Address Book program for a class and somewhere throughout my code I've gotten totally lost and can't seem to find out why I'm getting specific errors. It is currently made up of 3 programs. Menu.java, JGAddressBook.java and JursekGregChapter10t.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JursekGregChapter10t
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
     Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Welcome to JGAddressBook");
     ArrayList<JGAddressBook> list = new ArrayList<JGAddressBook>();

     while(true)
     {
        display();
        int ch=s.nextInt();
           if(ch==0)
           {
              System.out.println("Please Enter First Name: ");
              String a=s.nextLine();

              System.out.println("Please Enter Last Name: ");
              String b=s.nextLine();

              System.out.println("Please Enter Street Address: ");
              String c=s.nextLine();

              System.out.println("Please Enter City, State: ");
              String d=s.nextLine();

              System.out.println("Please Enter Zip Code: ");
              String e=s.nextLine();

              JGAddressBook item =new JGAddressBook(a,b,c,d,e);
              list.add(item);
           }

           else if((ch==1)||(ch==2)||(ch==3)||(ch==4)||(ch==5))

           {  
                 System.out.println("Please enter value to search for: ");
                 String q=s.nextLine();
                 JGAddressBook temp=search(list,q,ch);

              if(temp==null)
              {
                 System.out.println("No Entry Found");
              }  

              else
              {
                 System.out.println("First Name: "+temp.FirstName);
                 System.out.println("Last Name: "+temp.LastName);
                 System.out.println("Street Address: "+temp.StreetAddress);
                 System.out.println("City,State: "+temp.CityState);
                 System.out.println("Zip Code: "+temp.ZipCode);
                 System.out.println();
              }

           }

           else if(ch==6)
           {

           break;

           }

           else
           {
              System.out.println("Error: Invalid input");
           }

      }
   }
}
```

That is the first program, the second follows this and then the third

```
 import java.io.*;

 import java.util.*;


class JGAddressBook  {

   String FirstName;
   String LastName;
   String StreetAddress;
   String CityState;
   String ZipCode;

   public JGAddressBook()

      {

      FirstName="";
      LastName="";
      StreetAddress="";
      CityState="";
      ZipCode="";

      }  

   public JGAddressBook(String a,String b,String c,String d,String e)

      {
      FirstName=a;
      LastName=b;
      StreetAddress=c;
      CityState=d;
      ZipCode=e;
      }

   public void addEntry(String a,String b,String c,String d,String e)

      {
      FirstName=a;
      LastName=b;
      StreetAddress=c;
      CityState=d;
      ZipCode=e;
   }
}
```

and the third...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Menu
  {

  public static void display()
     {
     System.out.println("Menu: Press the following");
     System.out.println("0. Add New Entry");
     System.out.println("1. Search First Name");
     System.out.println("2. Search Last Name");
     System.out.println("3. Search Street Address");
     System.out.println("4. Search City, State");
     System.out.println("5. Search Zip Code");
     System.out.println("6. Exit ");
     }

  public static JGAddressBook search(ArrayList A, String c, int field)
  {
     JGAddressBook item=new JGAddressBook();

     for (int i=0; i < A.size(); i++)
        {
        item=(JGAddressBook) A.get(i);

        if(field==1)
        {
           if(item.FirstName.equals(c))
           return item;
        }

        else if(field==2) 
        {
           if(item.LastName.equals(c))
           return item;
        }

        else if(field==3)
        {
           if(item.StreetAddress.equals(c))
           return item;
        }

        else if(field==4)
        {
           if(item.CityState.equals(c))
           return item;
        }

        else
        {
           if(item.ZipCode.equals(c))
           return item;
        }

     }

     return null;

  }
}
```

The error I get is when compiling the first program and it is as follow:

```
/Users/Greg/Documents/Programming/Java/JursekGregChapter10t.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        display();
        ^
  symbol:   method display()
  location: class JursekGregChapter10t
/Users/Greg/Documents/Programming/Java/JursekGregChapter10t.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
                 JGAddressBook temp=search(list,q,ch);
                                    ^
  symbol:   method search(ArrayList<JGAddressBook>,String,int)
  location: class JursekGregChapter10t
2 errors
[Finished in 0.6s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error, you need to call the `static` `display()` method on your `Menu` object rather than trying to call `display()` from your `JursekGregChapter10t` class:

```
Menu.display();
```

Secondly, you are also calling `search(list,q,ch)` where as you should be calling `search(...)` on your Menu object:

```
Menu.search( list, q, ch );
```

Edit for further problem - When you use the `nextInt()` method, it does NOT consume the rest of the line. This means when you are prompted for a value in the interface,  the value is collected by the `nextInt()` method. Yet when you use the `nextLine()` method for the first name, `nextLine()` consumes the rest of the line up, and including, to the `\n`. What this means is that it consumes everything up to your input (just before it). So when `nextLine()` is called for last name, it consumes your first name and last name (up to the `\n`).

```
int ch=s.nextInt();
```

This is the fix:

```
int ch=s.nextInt();
s.nextLine();
```

Comment: I made the changes you listed and it did solve the error that was populated. When running the program at this point everything is working as far as inputing addresses. When I try to search I get the following error:               Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
 at JursekGregChapter10t.main(JursekGregChapter10t.java:16)

Comment: Can you provide your actions before this exception is thrown?

Comment: When I run the program, It allows me to enter information, it seems that it's capturing both the First and Last name information in only the Last Name variable. I found this by selecting any search function from the menu and at that point it fails asking me to select another menu option, after 2-3 attempts it throws those exceptions

Comment: For whatever reason, after trying to search a first name it displays all the information from that entry but the first name section is blank and last name has both First and Last name in it.

Comment: Edited my answer for you. Enjoy!

Comment: Zyn, The changes you offered fixed everything! The search functions are working properly. Thank you very much!